# Translate locations in bibliography depending on document/babel language

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, babel, languages

I often write texts in German and Englisch and use JabRef to organize my references. Citing a lot of conference papers, it is often quite annoying to always change the language of the locations according to the document language. So I wondered whether I could provide a kind of dictionary to biblatex, so I don't have to adapt my database every time.

E.g. in the preamble I'd like to define:

```
Munich = München
Germany = Deutschland
```

in case the document or babel language is `ngerman`.

Can this be done?

---

### MWE

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{filecontents}{bla.bib}
    @inproceedings{Orwell1984,
        author  = "George Orwell",
        title   = "1984",
        year    = "1948",
        booktitle = "Books about big brothers",
        location = "Munich, Germany",
    }
\end{filecontents}

\RequirePackage[backend=biber,style=ieee-alphabetic]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bla.bib}
\begin{document}
    \cite{Orwell1984}. \\
    \printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `biblatex`'s bibstrings to translate certain phrases. The question is what would be a good interface. If you want to be able to combine arbitrary terms in one field, you'd have to do something like the following (which feels a bit clunky).

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee-alphabetic]{biblatex}

\NewBibliographyString{munich,germany}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
  munich  = {München},
  germany = {Deutschland},
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{Orwell1984,
  author    = {George Orwell},
  title     = {1984},
  year      = {1948},
  booktitle = {Books about big brothers},
  location  = {\bibstring{munich}, \bibstring{germany}},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \autocite{Orwell1984}
  \printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

[image: G. Orwell, ”1984,“ in Books about big brothers, München, Deutschland, 1948.]

---

If you are OK with using only one string per field, you could make things a little nicer

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee-alphabetic]{biblatex}

\NewBibliographyString{de-munich}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
  de-munich  = {München},
}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  de-munich  = {Munich, Germany},
}

\DeclareListFormat{location}{%
  \usebibmacro{list:delim}{#1}%
  \ifbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{#1}}{#1}\isdot
  \usebibmacro{list:andothers}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{Orwell1984,
  author    = {George Orwell},
  title     = {1984},
  year      = {1948},
  booktitle = {Books about big brothers},
  location  = {de-munich},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \autocite{Orwell1984}
  \printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

[image: G. Orwell, ”1984,“ in Books about big brothers, München, 1948.]

---

A more BibTeX-y solution uses `@string`s. You can define strings for each location in different `.bib` files (one for each language) and then select the `.bib` file for the language you need in your document.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee-alphabetic]{biblatex}


\begin{filecontents}{locationstrings-german.bib}
@string{de:munich = "München"}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{locationstrings-english.bib}
@string{de:munich = "Munich, Germany"}
\end{filecontents}
% select the bib file for the language you want
\addbibresource{locationstrings-german.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{Orwell1984,
  author    = {George Orwell},
  title     = {1984},
  year      = {1948},
  booktitle = {Books about big brothers},
  location  = de:munich,
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
  \autocite{Orwell1984}
  \printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

[image: G. Orwell, ”1984,“ in Books about big brothers, München, 1948.]

---

The still very experimental multiscript version of `biblatex` might also be of interest: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/416

Comment: Thank you! My aim is to leave the original .bib file unmodified.. So I wonder if maybe your first approach allows something like `\DeclareFieldFormat{pubstate}{\ifbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{#1}}{#1}}`, so I won't have to define with bibstring withtin the bib-file. However, I could't manage to pass the two comma-separated values to the command. Do you think it can be done?

Comment: @thewaywewalk In theory you could try and use `etoolbox` CSV list macros to loop over the field as a comma-separated list. But that removes spaces around commas, so you'd have to manually re-add them. Furthermore, I believe that there is a difference between printable text and 'keys'/bibstring names (bibstring names should ideally use ASCII only for maximum compatibility, while printable text can consist of everything). ...

Comment: ...  I think you can't have your cake and eat it, too. **Either** go for fixed printable text in your `.bib` fields **or** for sane key markup (as shown in this or Ulrike's answer). Having both will get extremely messy at some point.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{filecontents}{german-strings.bib}
    @string{muenchen={München}}
    @string{germany={Deutschland}}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{bla.bib}
    @inproceedings{Orwell1984,
        author  = "George Orwell",
        title   = "1984",
        year    = "1948",
        booktitle = "Books about big brothers",
        location = muenchen # ", " # germany
    }
\end{filecontents}

\RequirePackage[backend=biber,style=ieee-alphabetic]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{german-strings.bib}
\addbibresource{bla.bib}
\begin{document}
    \cite{Orwell1984}. \\
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It appears to be impossible to leave the original .bib-file unmodified, is that right?

Comment: The multiscript version of biblatex and biber are now in CTAN as separate packages `biblatex-ms` and `biber-ms`. They can be installed in parallel with the normal packages to try out. Feedback welcome.

Comment: @PLK I saw the announcement and I will try to look at some time.

Comment: There is a basic, new example doc (`texdoc 98-multiscript`) and the [source](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/multiscript/doc/latex/biblatex/examples/98-multiscript.tex) for that is heavily commented.